Google Sheets pivot table custom filter to check if ITEM is present in a different list
I'm trying to run a custom filter on a pivot table to change which rows are shown. Without any filters, the rows shown will be all Businesses, e.g.,:
Red Lobster
Shake Shack
Chili's
In-and-out
McDonald's
4505 Meats

However, I only want to show the rows with the names of Businesses that are present in another list, say the other list is:
4505 Meats
In-and-out
Shack Shack

I could do this by adding a standard filter, and simply searching for the names of the 3 companies on the short list. See image below

However, this won't work for me because the short list of Businesses I want to "check" in the filter is actually dynamic.
I see that there is a Custom Formula option to filter, but I don't know how to write this formula? I basically want to say, show me Businesses that exist in another list. So if the other list were, say A5:A10, something like =countif(A5:A10,X) > 0 where X refers to each individual Business that the software is evaluating.

=COUNTIF(<lookup_range>, <field_name>)

=COUNTIF(A5:A10, Business)

If your field name contains spaces, enclose it in 'single quotes'.

WHY was this impossible to find in their docs arg thank you so much

I agree it wasn't quick to find.
